# How to convert List<Integer> into List<String>?

Tags: java

```
public String largestNumber(final List<Integer> A) {

}
```

I want to continue this method , but data inside the list should be in strings.
I do not know how to convert it.

Comment: Why would you want to convert to `List<String>` when the return type is `String`?

Comment: Why would you want to return a string from a method called "largest number", that takes its inputs as numbers?

Comment: Note: Strings are sorted differently to Integer so converting them to a String will change the way largest is determined.e.g. `9 < 88` but  `"9".compareTo("88") > 0`

Answer (score 0):

What is the logic to convert an integer to a `String`. The solution should be something like this.

```
ints.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have provided the directions on how to convert the `List<Integer>` to `List<String>`. However, given the name of the method, I would presume the goal is to find the largest number in the specified `List<Integer>`. I would think it should be returned as an `int` and not a `String`, based on the method name. Nonetheless, one possible approach for actually finding the largest value and returning it as a `String` would be:

```
public String largestNumber(final List<Integer> myNumbers)
  throws NoSuchElementException
{
    if (myNumbers == null || myNumbers.isEmpty()) {
        // could return an empty String instead, but then the
        // calling method might need to check for an empty String
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No numbers provided");
    }

    // use the stream to find the largest (max) value
    OptionalInt possMax = myNumbers.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).max();

    return String.valueOf(possMax.getAsInt());
}
```

Note too that I am allowing the `NoSuchElementException` if there is no largest number to propagate. Checks for the existence and then returning an empty `String` could be provided, but returning an empty `String` seems like the calling code would then possibly need to check for such a condition.

```
List<Integer> vals = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1);
String l = largestNumber(vals);
System.out.println(l);
```

Output:

> 5

Answer (score -1):

- Convert the `List<Integer>` in a `Stream`
- Map each value from `Integer` to `String`
- Collect the stream as `List<String>`

```
list.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: This wont compile.

Comment: Indeed. Wrong Method reference